# After upgrading spring-jms from 4.0.2 to 4.3.8, we started facing communication related issues it seems

Tags: spring-jms

we just upgraded our spring jars from 4.0.2 to 4.3.8 and one of them was spring-jms.

Now, we started facing the login issue on our web apps where it has to communicate the user info with our security module through activemq (apache-activemq-5.13.0).

we have not touched our mq version. seems like the messages are getting delivered to the queue consumer with a long delay and this delay is random (as sometimes we don't see much of a delay).

Not sure whats going on, I replaced the spring-jms back to 4.0.2 and all login attempts just works fine like within 3 seconds.

Any ideas or suggestions what to look for ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for putting it late, but we figured out the issue which was the cache level on spring jms listener (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) was set as zero which means none but for some odd reason with jar 4.0.2 it was the caching of JMS objects still but when we used the upgraded jar 4.3.8 the cache was not there so it was creating/dropping jms objects and making it slower. After setting the right cache level the slowness went away.